# Most efficient way to find connections between the nodes in Cypher / Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I need to find connections between all the nodes (with a "Hashtag" label) connected to the main user node.

So far, I came up with a solution like this, but it seems to me a bit inefficient, because I traverse the graph twice to first find c1 and then c2.

Anybody has better ideas?

```
MATCH (u:User{uid:"777"}), (c1:Hashtag), (c2:Hashtag), 
c1-[:BY]->u, c2-[:BY]->u, c1-[rel:TO]->c2 RETURN rel,c1,c2;
```

(I'm working with Neo4J / Cypher 2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, play around with it and let me know the output.

```
MATCH (u:User {uid:"777"})
WITH u
MATCH u<-[:BY]-(c1:Hashtag)-[rel:TO]-(c2:Hashtag)--(u)
RETURN rel, c1, c2
```

Basically, the idea here is as follow:

1. Match the User node first
2. Use it to match all 'Hashtag' nodes
3. Use it to match to all 'Hashtag' nodes connected to the previous 'Hashtag nodes
4. Return the 'rel', which is all the relationships from 'Hashtag' nodes to 'Hashtag' nodes which are connected to the user 777

Comment: seems to work much faster, thanks! :) let's wait what the others say a bit... great idea!

Comment: but one problem, then we get c2 nodes that are not necessarily connected with :BY to the user... and I need all of them connected to the user. so perhaps we should add ...(c2:Hashtag)-[:BY]->u but then it's kind of the same as above...

Comment: oh i tried already adding u and it works (also adding directions to <-[rel:TO] and -[:BY]-u) both requests seem to take the same amount of time, and running them with PROFILE prefix in neo4j-sh shows exactly the same result actually.